# Como retornar os valores de uma public List<weather>?

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um aplicativo em Windows Forms de Clima/Tempo

Quero puxar os dados da Descriçao dentro da Classe Weather

```
public class weather
{
    public string descrição { get; set; }
}

void getWeather(string city)
{
    using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
    {
        string url = string.Format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={0}&appid={1}&units=metric&cnt==6", city, APPID);

        var json = web.DownloadString(url);

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<weatherInfo.root>(json);

        weatherInfo.root outPut = result;

        txtCidade.Text = string.Format("{0}", outPut.name);
        txtdescricao.Text = string.Format("{0}", outPut.sys.country);
        txtTemp.Text = string.Format("{0} \u00B0" + "C", outPut.main.temp);
        txtSensacao.Text = string.Format("{0} \u00B0" + "C", outPut.main.feels_like);
        txtHumidity.Text = string.Format("{0}" + "%", outPut.main.humidity);
        txtdescricao.Text = string.Format("{0}" + "%", outPut.weather.descricao);// O erro ocorre aqui, mas porque? 
    }
}

class weatherInfo
{
    public class coord
    {
        public double lon { get; set; }
        public double lat { get; set; }
    }

    public class weather
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string descrição { get; set; }
        public string main { get; set; }
    }

    public class main
    {
        public double temp { get; set; }
        public double pressure { get; set; }
        public double humidity { get; set; }
        public double feels_like { get; set; }
        public double temp_min { get; set; }
    }

    public class wind
    {
        public double speed { get; set; }
    }

    public class sys
    {
        public string country { get; set; }
    }

    public class root
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public sys sys { get; set; }
        public double dt { get; set; }
        public wind wind { get; set; }
        public main main { get; set; }
        public List<weather> weather { get; set; }
        public coord coord { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Só que ele me retorna esse Erro

> CS1061    ‘List<weatherInfo.weather>’ não contém uma definição para
> "descricao" e não foi possível encontrar nenhum método de extensão
> "descricao" que aceite um primeiro argumento do tipo
> ‘List<weatherInfo.weather>’

Ja tentei:

```
txtdescricao.Text = string.Format("{0}" + "%", outPut.weather);
txtdescricao.Text = string.Format("{1}", outPut.weather);
```

Como eu consigo retornar os Resultados

```
public int id { get; set; }
public string descrição { get; set; }
public string main { get; set; }
```

Para uma Label?

Comment: Vc está tentando pegar um valor diretamente do List, se vc quiser pegar a descrição o recomendável é juntar as strings, ou pegar uma descrição específica do list. Exemplo `outPut.weather[0].descrição)`

Comment: O JSON contém **uma lista** de `weather` ou tem somente um?

Comment: Deu certo ?....

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado pelas respostas!!

Answer (score 0):

O retorno dessa informação é um [json](/questions/tagged/json) com o seguinte formato:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": -46.64,
    "lat": -23.55
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 25.56,
    "feels_like": 22.86,
    "temp_min": 25.56,
    "temp_max": 25.56,
    "pressure": 1012,
    "humidity": 44
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 4.92,
    "deg": 327,
    "gust": 5.81
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 0
  },
  "dt": 1603889573,
  "sys": {
    "type": 3,
    "id": 2033898,
    "country": "BR",
    "sunrise": 1603873367,
    "sunset": 1603919858
  },
  "timezone": -10800,
  "id": 3448439,
  "name": "São Paulo",
  "cod": 200
}
```

onde o `weather` é um `array` de um tipo de dado e em cada posição não existe a tal ***descrição***, mas, no caso ***description*** e para acessar precisa passar para o código a posição, porque `array` pode ou não possuir itens e cada posição dentro desse `array` vai representar um dado tipo.

No seu código então:

```
txtdescricao.Text = string.Format("{0}" + "%", outPut.weather[0].description);
```

mas, o correto é saber se essa lista tem algum item, então ainda eu faria assim:

```
txtdescricao.Text = "Não há resultado";
if (outPut.weather.Count() > 0) 
{
    txtdescricao.Text = string.Format("{0}" + "%", outPut.weather[0].description);
}
```

Fique atento a esses detalhes básicos e estude mais a linguagem e como funciona.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!! irei estudar mais sobre a API